# flutter dart datetime in list<map> occur error

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

my code is below. I want it to be type-recognized as a datetime type at compile time.

```dart
var myList = [{
   'message': 'foo',
   'time': DateTime.now()
}];
DateTime.now().difference(myList[0]['time']);
```

and it has error of `The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'.`

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a type cast for this with the `as` keyword:

```dart
DateTime.now().difference(myList[0]['time'] as DateTime)
```

Comment: i love this! thanks